# Inconsistency between PhantomJS and "classic" browser when using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, phantomjs, mocha.js

I am executing the following code in some Mocha tests:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
$.get('./rsc/some.xml').done(function(data) {
    console.log(typeof data);
});
```

In Chrome or FF, data is an XML document, in PhantomJS, data is a string. IMHO, the former is the correct behavior since jQuery is able to "intelligently" guess the data type before resolving the promise.

That difference makes my tests fail when executed in the command line (PhantomJS) while they pass in a classic browser. Do you have any idea?

For the record, I'am using jQuery 2.1.1 and PhantomJS 1.9.7

Comment: First off, check that the server is returning correct headers for XML. And try setting the `dataType` argument of `$.get` to `"xml"`. If that doesn't help, you should debug/step through the code in PhantomJS. Maybe you can see that way, why jQuery doesn't recognize the data as XML.

Comment: @RoToRa, indeed the `dataType` being set to `xml` is doing the stuff, thanks. Still, the question remains. I shall post an issue to PhantomJS guys.

Comment: For those who might ask, my tests were not failing because of string vs object data type but because of PhantomJS DOM API missing the "children" property.